# How to construct examples of functions in the Spaces of type $\mathcal{S}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, gelfand-shilov-spaces

There are $3$  $\mathcal{S}$-type Spaces, namely $\mathcal{S}_\alpha\:,\: \mathcal{S}^\beta\:,\:\mathcal{S}_\alpha^\beta$. They are defined by:

- $\mathcal{S}_\alpha: |x^k\varphi^{(q)}(x)|\le C_qA^kk^{k\alpha}\qquad (k,q=0,1,2,...)$
- $\mathcal{S}^\beta: |x^k\varphi^{(q)}(x)|\le C_kB^qq^{q\beta}\qquad (k,q=0,1,2,...)$
- $\mathcal{S}_\alpha^\beta: |x^k\varphi^{(q)}(x)|\le CA^kB^qk^{k\alpha}q^{q\beta}\qquad (k,q=0,1,2,...)$

where the constants $A,B,C_k,C_q$ depend on $\varphi \:\&\:\alpha+\beta\ge1$.

In the first space we have functions which are rapidly decaying as $|x|\to \infty$. The second space imposes conditions on the growth of derivatives of these functions as $|x|\to \infty$. The third space $$\mathcal{S}_\alpha^\beta\subset\mathcal{S}_\alpha\cap \mathcal{S}^\beta$$In general the converse also holds which is a classical result due to Kashpirovsky. I want to construct examples to get a better understanding of these definitions. From the definition it is clear that every function in these spaces is at least $C_c^\infty$. So intuitively the first thing that comes to my mind is Gaussian-like functions. Now say I consider $\mathcal{S}_1^2(\mathbb{R})$. Which type of functions belong to this space ? How to come up with suitable constants ?

Reference: Generalized Functions, Volume 2 by I.M.Gelfand and G.E. Shilov

Comment: I see you created new tag called (gelfand-shilov). Is it intended for [Gelfand-Shilov spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Shilov_space)? As a tag creator, could you perhaps take some time to explain the intended usage in the [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/gelfand-shilov/info)?

Comment: Yeah, I will add details to the tags

Comment: @MartinSleziak, I added details.... But haven't got any answer for my question

Comment: It is not really my area, so I will probably not be able to help you. There is some advice in [help center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) and [on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question). (But since you've been around for some time, you probably know about that.) I should add that I appreciate that you have edited the tag-info.

Comment: I changed the tag from (gelfand-shilov) to (gelfand-shilov-spaces) because Gelfand-Shilov could be a little bit ambiguous (could refer to the books).

Comment: @CameronWilliams, thank you !! It looks better !!