# Laplace transform of functions related to type $\mathcal{S}$, and the relation to entire functions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, distribution-theory, gelfand-shilov-spaces

I have doubts in the following two questions      :

1. What is the Laplace transform of $[x^k\varphi(x)]^{(q)}$, where $\varphi\in \mathcal{S}_\alpha^\beta$ and $-\infty<x<\infty$ , $k,q=0,1,2,...$?

I know that the Fourier transform of $[x^k\varphi(x)]^{(q)}$ is $\xi^q\varphi^{(k)}(x)$. Also we know that Fourier transform takes differentiation to polynomial multiplication. Does a similar result hold for laplace Transform also or is it different ?

2. How to prove the following assertion:

If an entire function $\varphi$ satisfies $$|\varphi(x+iy)|\le C\exp(a|x|^h+b|y|^{\gamma}), \:\:\:h\le\gamma$$ 
where $a\lt0$ and $C>0$, then $\varphi\in \mathcal{S}_{1/h}^{1-1/{\gamma}}$, where $\mathcal{S}_\alpha^\beta$ is the Gelfand-Shilov space of type $\mathcal{S}$ defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372195/how-to-construct-examples-of-functions-in-the-spaces-of-type-mathcals)
Any help will be welcome. Thanks..

Reference: Generalized Functions, Volume 2, by I.M Gelfand and G.E. Shilov